# Forming a sanitised query string for pattern search in SQLite3 and Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Im trying to form a sanitised query string in Python to use in SQLite3. It needs to take the ultimate form:

```
SELECT * FROM Players WHERE PlayerName LIKE '%bob%'
```

...so I can run a pattern search.

Ideally I want to have a ? in the query so I can then insert the search string when running the query and prevent *Bobby Tables* type events from occurring (not that I'll have to worry about that tbh):

```
search_string = "bob"

query = "SELECT * FROM Players WHERE PlayerName LIKE '%?%'"

cur.execute(query, (search_string))
```

Running this gives me:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
>   current statement uses 0, and there are 3 supplied.

So I'm pretty sure the issue is both with the use of the single quotes, percents and question marks but am fairly stuck - I can't form the query so that python sees it needs a binding.

What is the best way round this or is there better practice for forming sanitised queries for pattern search in SQL?

UPDATE: final line was:

```
cur.execute(query, [('%' + search_string + '%')])
```

Comment: What is in `search_string`?

Comment: It's a raw_input passed to the function as "search_string".

Comment: What is an example of a value of it that you are passing in?

Comment: It's typed text, for example if you're searching for "M Markovic", the search_string might be "marko"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the lone placeholder `?` after `LIKE` and wrap `search_string` with `%` during parameter assignment:

```
...
search_string = 'bob'
query = 'SELECT * FROM Players WHERE PlayerName LIKE ?'
cur.execute(query, ('%' + search_string + '%'))
```

Comment: Thank you! I find this slightly cleaner. The final line was:   cur.execute(query, [('%' + search_string + '%')])

Answer (score 0):

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Players WHERE PlayerName LIKE '%' + ? + '%'"
```

You just have to separate the variable (?).

Comment: Thank you! It's now expecting one binding - unfortunately, the number of bindings I seem to be supplying is equal to the number of letters in the string I pass to it, even if I substitute quoted text. Can you help once more please?

Comment: `(thing)` is an expression that evaluates to `thing`, so `cur.execute(query, (search_string))` is the same as `cur.execute(query, search_string)`. (It should be clear why you're getting multiple bindings now.). You want to pass a single-item collection, e.g. `[search_string]` (a list) or `(search_string,)` (a tuple--note the comma!).

Comment: Thank you Francis. I think I just can just about visualise what was going on! The final line I used was `cur.execute(query, [('%' + search_string + '%')])`